# How to make C3.js Style Changes Apply to Only One Chart

Tags: javascript, html, css, c3.js

I am trying to style the axis on one of my `C3.js` graphs and I understand that to do this I must modify the `css` file for the `C3.js` code, but these changes I make in this file apply to every `C3.js` chart on my site. My question is how I can make a change that will apply to only one of my charts.

For example, this is the style that I want to change:

```
.c3 path, .c3 line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
}
```

and this is how I have my `C3.js` chart added to my HTML body:

```
<div id="scan_duration_chart_container"></div>
```

in my chart creation, I added the field `bindto: '#scan_duration_chart_container'` so that my chart would get inserted at this `div` tag.

Now, with all this setup I **assumed** that I could do it by adding this after the default style:

```
#scan_duration_chart_container .c3 path, .c3 line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: white;
}
```

but this had no effect on any chart, which I am guessing is because the original style is overriding it. How do I make it so that it will only affect the one chart within `scan_duration_chart_container` and nothing else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested a few options and found that the following will work:

```
#scan_duration_chart_container.c3 line,
#scan_duration_chart_container.c3 path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: white;
}
```

I have created a fiddle example with two charts, the second one shows the modified css settings: http://jsfiddle.net/du46zptL/5/

Comment: was about to post the same, they have two selectors for the declaration but they only added the #id qualifer to the first one (plus the fact the element with the id is the c3 class so removing the space is necessary or it'll look for a non-existent child element of class c3)